# Pattern matching a string

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate that a string is of the following format/sequence

```
LGaaaaaaaaaaYYMMDDnnnnn
```

For the string to be valid, it has to start with the characters "LG" followed by 10 characters followed by a date in the format (YYMMDD) following by 5 digits.

Here is what i have come up with

```
String patter = ^LG{1}[a-z][A-Z]{10}[0-9]{6}[0-9]{5}
```

- How can i check that the string does start with "LG"
- How do i check that ten characters after "LG" are indeed after the characters "LG"
- How do i check that YYMMDD is a valid date
- How can i check that the digits at the end of the string are exactly 5 digits.

-- 
I could use Simpledateformat to validate the string as a date i think.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? You are almost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think your regular expression should be more like: `LG[a-zA-Z]{10}[0-9]{6}[0-9]{5}`
2. If the string matches the pattern, use substring to pull out the date and parse it with SimpleDateFormat to validate that it is truly a good date.

Comment: What is the effect of removing ^ from the begining of the expression? I thought would ensure that the string will be valid if LG was at the start of the string.

Comment: ^ means not, you actually want to match LG instead of not matching LG.

Comment: ^ means actually the beginning of the string in some cases. You are thinking of [^a] which means not.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you use it. If you use the [Mather.matches](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) method then the ^ is not really needed because it will match against the whole string. If you use find() method instead then the ^ will make a difference